# C++ overloaded operator->() not being called?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Can anyone please explain why the overloaded operator -> for class Foo is not being called from a pointer of type Foo *?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
Foo * operator -> () {
    cout << "calling Foo * operator -> ()\n";
    return this;
}
    int x;
};


void main() {
    Foo f;
    Foo * pF = &f;
    pF->x;                  // Why is overloaded operator-> not being called here?
    (pF->operator->())->x;  // This works.

    cout << "End test.\n";
}
```

Comment: The second statement works because you are essentially calling the operator -> method using your pointer pF. There is no overloading going on there. As answered below you can only overload operators for instances not pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is overloaded operator-> not being called here?

Because `pF` is a pointer, not a `Foo` instance. You have overloaded `operator->` for `Foo`, not `Foo*`. You may call your overloaded `operator->` directly on `f`.

```
f->x;
```

You may not overload `operator->` for `Foo*` or any other pointer type.

Comment: Well, there goes my hope for a implicit pointer virtual address system.  Give client a Foo *, be able to move Foo object in memory (optimization), have Foo * still point to correct object.  Looks like I'll have use a smart pointer container class.

Answer (score 3):

You overloaded it for `Foo`, not for `Foo*` (which is impossible).

This would have worked:

```
(f.operator->())->x;
```

Or, of course:

```
f->x;
```

Being able to use that short syntax is the entire purpose of the overload, no? Although it's quite confusing to just return a pointer to the same object you invoked the operator on.

Comment: Why so roundabout way of calling? Why not just `f->x`?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Yeah or that. I wanted to keep the OP's intent but fix their direct bug.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: No. The entire point of `operator->` is to make `f->x` work lol

Answer (score 2):

You have overloaded "point-to" operator of the type `Foo`, not type `Foo*`.

```
class Foo {
public:
    // Overload 'point-to' operator of 'Foo'
    Foo * operator -> () {
        cout << "calling Foo * operator -> ()\n";
        return this;
    }
    int x;
};
```

Example of usage:

```
Foo f;
f.operator->();
```